# How to compare two lists in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a program which takes a list containing lists, and then compares the lists inside. If any two lists contain the same information, such as them both containing X, then I want to remove X from both lists. How could I go about this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
dedupe(Lists, Result) :-
    append(Lists, Flat),
    findall(E, (select(E, Flat, FlatNoE), \+ memberchk(E, FlatNoE)), Uniques),
    subtract(Flat, Uniques, Unwanted),
    findall(Rs, (member(Ls, Lists), subtract(Ls, Unwanted, Rs)), Result).
```

e.g.

```
?- dedupe([[1,2,3], [1,2,5,6,1], [4,1,2,1]], R).
R = [[3], [5, 6], [4]]
```

The design is:

- we need to remove duplicates from each sublist
- duplicates are found by finding all the elements, finding the unique elements, and removing those from all leaving the duplicate elements.
- All elements are found by flattening the nested lists with `append/2`.
- Unique elements are found by taking one element out at a time with `select` and seeing if that element still exists in the rest of the values with `memeberchk`.
- `subtract` does a list-from-list subtraction to remove the unique elements from all the elements, leaving the `Unwanted` duplicate elements.
- The last `findall` then runs subtract over the sublists, removing the duplicaates from each one.

It's possible in SWI Prolog to rewrite the last line as:

```
maplist({Unwanted}/[Ls, Ls_]>>subtract(Ls, Unwanted, Ls_), Lists, Result).
```

fwiw. In small testing they have almost identical timing/inferences to solve.